# yii CJuiAutoComplete not working online but working fine locally

Tags: php, yii

I have been working on my yii project for some time now. All is working fine locally but when I upload it online, all the CJuiAutoComplete input fields don't work. No autocomplete options are given when the user starts typing in the input field.
What is wrong?
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the CJuiAutoComplete importing  path.
Linux server is case sensitive.
If real path is "Name/Script.php" then you can not use "name/script.php"